# Git: do not push file to repository but keep file there

Tags: git, heroku

I have a git repository on Heroku for an app. My app writes information to  a database **db.csv** which I have previously committed.

Now, whenever I make changes to other files and then commit:

```
git commit -am "something"
git push heroku master
```

The database file gets overwritten. I've tried adding a .gitignore file but this deletes the file from the repository so is no longer on the hosting site. Any suggestions?

Comment: i hope you're not writing to this file during runtime in production, as each dyno's filesystem is isolated and ephemeral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to stage your files individually rather than adding & committing with a single command.

```
git add file1 file2 ...
git commit -m "something"
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

The .gitignore file won't delete your file, it will just ignore it (as the name stands).

Maybe you deleted it, and then commited the deletion. If you want to ignore a file already tracked, you have to add this file to the .gitignore AND do a

```
git rm --cached db.csv
git commit
```

The --cached option will keep your file but stop tracking it.